# how can I save data to cloud firebase as number from textformfield in flutter

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, flutter

I form which contain some textformfield in which one field is price which i want to save as number not string ..below is my code of Textformfield

```
 new TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      style: new TextStyle(fontFamily: "ChelaOne-Regular",
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 20.0),
                      decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "Price",
                          labelStyle: new TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: "ChelaOne-Regular",
                              color: Colors.white),
                          hintText: "Please enter Price ",
                          hintStyle: new TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: "ChelaOne-Regular",
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 15.0)),
                      validator: (val) =>
                      val.isEmpty
                          ? 'Please enter Discribtion'
                          : null,
                        onSaved: (val) => price = val,
                    ),
```

my code to save data is

```
Firestore.instance.collection('item').document().setData({
        "Discribtion": discribtion,
        "Title": title,
        "price":price,

      });
      Done();
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }
  }
```

where price is a num(num price;)
please help me in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String numString = '3';
int numInt = int.parse(numString);
```

So you would do something like this:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('item').document().setData({
        "Discribtion": discribtion,
        "Title": title,
        "price":int.parse(price),

      });
```